# Sentinelsat group tiles

Tags: python, sentinel-2, sentinelsat

I query sentinel-2 products for a large shape by using python library which is sentinelsat. This query returns a lot of data, some of them is belongs to same tile but their date is different. Is it possible to group this same tiles and process them ?

```
import sentinelsat
import pandas

geometry = {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        43.552852,
        38.724315
      ],
      [
        43.552852,
        36.614646
      ],
      [
        37.81111,
        36.614646
      ],
      [
        37.81111,
        38.724315
      ],
      [
        43.552852,
        38.724315
      ]
    ]
  ]
}

footprint = sentinelsat.geojson_to_wkt(geometry)
path_filter = sentinelsat.make_path_filter("*GRANULE/*/IMG_DATA/*_B0[48]_10m.jp2")
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = ('20220801',"20220815"),
                     platformname = "Sentinel-2")
products = pandas.DataFrame(products).T
products = products[products.processinglevel == "Level-2A"]
```

I used footprint to group the same tiles. However, I am not sure of whether it is right approch or not.

Comment: According to the [Sentinel-2 MSI naming convention guide](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/naming-convention) you should be able to find information on the tile ID in the file name.

Comment: @ChloeG many thanks for his information, it will solve my problem. Tileid column is in products daframe as well. However, it is always nan, is it a bug ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I don't know about the dataframe.